# bootstrap3: container наезжает на верхний div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть два одинаковых блока, им необходимо задать тень, которая должна выделять их поверх `container`. Но при этом `container` заезжает на верхний блок, отчего тень перекрывается фоном `container` и оттого видна лишь частично. При этом с нижним блоком всё в порядке.
Как исправить этот непорядок с верхним блоком?

html

```
<div class="footer text-center text-uppercase">
  <p>Заголовок Заголовок Заголовок</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="header text-center">
            <h1 class="text-uppercase"> <strong>Заголовок</strong></h1>
                <h2>Подзаголовок</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer text-center text-uppercase">
  <p>Заголовок Заголовок Заголовок</p>
</div>
```

css

```
body {
    background-color: #eee;
}
.container {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.footer {
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #699;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

Для большего удобства пример на CodePan: https://codepen.io/kjurrt/pen/PJzqVB/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Как исправить этот непорядок с верхним блоком?*

Это, как раз таки, и есть порядок, т.к. по умолчанию в общем потоке блоки идут друг за другом и друг над другом.

Чтобы изменить порядок наложения элементов друг на друга, используйте [`z-index`](https://webref.ru/css/z-index):

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.container {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.footer {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #699;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="footer text-center text-uppercase">
  <p>Заголовок Заголовок Заголовок</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="header text-center">
      <h1 class="text-uppercase"> <strong>Заголовок</strong></h1>
      <h2>Подзаголовок</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer text-center text-uppercase">
  <p>Заголовок Заголовок Заголовок</p>
</div>
```